# They also serve who only stand and wait. What is the function of "who only............wait"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, clauses, direct-objects

Is the part "who only ...wait" a noun clause acting as direct object?

I am confused because the verb "serve" is shown to be an intransitive verb in the book in this particular example.

Comment: Read it as "They who only stand and wait also serve."

Comment: So I am correct about the noun clause part. What if i think it like :"They also serve him". Replace 'him' by the 'clause'. I think the way you re-framed the sentence changed the meaning.

Comment: Incorrect.  "They also serve him" is not the same as "He also serves".

Comment: (The clause beginning with "who" is modifying "they".  It is not the object of "serve".)

Answer (score 1):

> They also serve who only stand and wait,

is a line from a [poem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_His_Blindness) Poets have the license to move clauses around so as to make their poems scan and rhyme.  Don't be misled into thinking that this is a common or generally acceptable sentence structure; it's very unusual. As the comments say, the usual word order would be

> They who only stand and wait also serve.